# How to "clear" an array in c to make room for a smaller array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory

I have an array in C, let's suppose it's

```
**arr = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
```

through some function, I populate this array in such a way that it ends up being

```
arr = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", ... "tenth"};
```

Now, if I want to populate it anew, so that it's

```
arr = {"1st", "2nd", "3rd"}; //Desired outcome
```

it instead is shown as

```
arr = {"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "fourth", "fifth", ... "tenth"}; //Actual outcome
```

I'm certain my code is wrong, and my function for populating it from empty is fine, but I just want to find a way to wipe it. I tried free(), but I either used it wrong or that's not what I should be using.

Do any of you have a function that can not just set a string to `"\0"`, but completely eradicate it?

---

To all that commented and answered, thank you.

What I was doing was using text files, strtok, and strdup to read words from a file into a `char` double pointer. I don't want any more than 5000 words stored in the "array", even if my file is 5001+ words.

I did this. I successfully populated the memory with the strings from the file. But if I changed my mind and tried to populate the memory with a smaller file (~30 words), it would change the first 30 and leave the remaining 4970 as they were, when I wanted them not to exist.

Comment: Only `arr` is not an array....

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of your attempt to show us. And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: So... is `arr` declared as `char ****arr`?

Comment: How exactly does your code determine the size of the array?

Comment: Please show the code how you access `arr` and how you find out where the end of `arr` is or how many elements are actually used. To mark entries as unused you could fill the array with `NULL` pointers or write a `NULL` pointer after the last used element.

Comment: C does not have whole-array assignment, and you are not using compound literals, so it's unclear how to interpret the code you present.  It would be best to update the question to contain an MCVE, as has already been requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use realloc function to change capacity of your arr variable:`arr = realloc(arr, 3 * sizeof(char*))` - reallocate memory for 3 elements. Then you should assign these 3 elements to your arr

Comment: Thank you! I was about to delete my question, because it was admittedly vague what I was trying to accomplish, but your solution worked. On the off-chance someone in the future can read my question, understand what I was trying to do, and read your answer to find out, I'll leave it up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `realloc` function:

Syntax: `void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);`

The  realloc()  function  changes  the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged in the  range  from  the  start  of  the region  up  to the minimum of the old and new sizes.  If the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be initialized.  If ptr is  NULL,  then  the call  is  equivalent  to  malloc(size),  for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless ptr  is NULL,  it  must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc() or real‐loc().  If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *arr = malloc(sizeof(strlen(arr)) + 1);
    strcpy(arr, "Hello World!");

    char *arr_new = realloc(arr, sizeof(strlen(arr_new)) + 1);
    strcpy(arr_new, "Hello!");

    if(arr != NULL) {
        free(arr);
    // Free whatever used

  }
  return 0;
}
```